# iTunes alternative for Windows with good podcast management?

Tags: windows, itunes, podcasts

Since iTunes is so dog-slow on Windows, I'm looking for a good alternative that manages podcasts well. Bonus for syncing play counts, ratings, etc.

Edit: I'm not looking for a podcast-only app, I'm looking for a music manager that does well with podcasts.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1767/podcast-desktop-app

Comment: Not a dupe - see edit

Comment: @Aidan: I see. Might want to re-word the title also, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) rocks. It can handle your music collection management, podcasts and it syncs with many different devices.

Answer (score 6):

Well I really like the [Zune software](http://www.zune.net/en-us/software/download/default.htm)... It made me buy a Zune!

Answer (score 3):

You might check out [Songbird](http://sourceforge.net/projects/songbird.mirror/).  Not only will it manage your local music, but it is very nice for finding music on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to respond directly to a comment yet...

Although MediaMonkey is great, please be aware that even the latest version of MediaMonkey no longer synchronizes with the iPhone under the 3.0 OS.  It's read-only.  It worked fine with the 2.x OS, and it still works fine with my older generation iPods.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case anymore with the latest release: http://www.mediamonkey.com/news/2009/11/19/mediamonkey-3-2-released-syncs-with-the-latest-phones/

Comment: Yep, I saw that.  It'll always be a game of catch-up, of course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/ for a while, I found it quite attractive and useful. Now I use itunes, because I'm lazy.